# how to use one loop to add to multiple groups

Tags: python, loops, pygame

I'm trying to make a game, and I need to add sprites to a series of groups using loops (4 in each group).

I'm currently using many separate loops to add them to the different groups. Is it at all possible to shorten this?

```
i = 0

while i <= 3:
    Circle = Circles(0)
    guess1.add(Circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(Circle)

i = 0

while i <= 3:
    Circle = Circles(0)
    guess2.add(Circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(Circle)

i = 0

while i <= 3:
    Circle = Circles(0)
    guess3.add(Circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(Circle)

i = 0

while i <= 3:
    Circle = Circles(0)
    guess4.add(Circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(Circle)
```

Comment: did you ever try to use one loop - one `while` ?

Comment: your main problem is that inside `while` you doesn't change `i` so it should never ends first loop. If you know how many items to create then use `for i in range(4):`

Comment: @furas ok, so I'm changing i now, but that doesn't really solve my problem.

Comment: maybe your problem is totally different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that you don't have `i += 1` in loops so first loop should never end.

```
i = 0

while i <= 3:
    i += 1

    circle = Circles(0)
    guess1.add(circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(circle)

    circle = Circles(0)
    guess2.add(circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(circle)

    circle = Circles(0)
    guess3.add(circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(circle)

    circle = Circles(0)
    guess4.add(circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(circle)
```

But if you know how many items to create then use `for`-loop and you will no need `i = 0` and `i += 1`

```
for i in range(4):

    circle = Circles(0)
    guess1.add(circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(circle)

    circle = Circles(0)
    guess2.add(circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(circle)

    circle = Circles(0)
    guess3.add(circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(circle)

    circle = Circles(0)
    guess4.add(circle)
    all_sprites_list.add(circle)
```

---

BTW: There is good rule to use `UpperCaseNames` for class name but `lower_case_name` for instances - `circle = Circles(0)`

Answer (score 1):

Pygame's [`Sprite` class](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite) takes a list of arguments (`*args`), which is any number of groups the sprite should be added.

So when you subclass the `Sprite` class, you can make use of that like this:

```
class Circle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, index, *args):
        super.__init__(*args)
        ....
```

Also, you can iterate over a list of Groups, ending with something like this:

```
for guess in [guess1, guess2, guess3, guess4]:
    for i in range(4):
        Circles(i, guess, all_sprites_list)
```